# How to avoid overlapping between boxes and whiskers in boxplot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, boxplot, overlap

When trying not to show outlines while plotting boxes in a boxplot, whiskers may overlap. Is there a way to avoid it? (perhaps changing the order patches are display and send whiskers behind)

Consider this minimal reproducible example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

bp = plt.boxplot([1,2,3], patch_artist=True)
plt.setp(bp['boxes'], color='#5454c6')
for item in ['whiskers', 'caps']:
    plt.setp(bp[item], lw=5)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Mabye `for item in ['whiskers', 'caps']: plt.setp(bp[item], lw=5, zorder=0)`? That would put the whiskers behind the box. (Setting the color for the whiskers to e.g. `'lime'` seems to better illustrate the problem with the undesired overlap.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem is the linewidth extending the line length.
See https://stackoverflow.com/a/66330477/13636407

So main solution would be to use `setp(..., solid_capstyle="butt")`.
But also drawing the whiskers below the boxes as mentioned in comments will do the job.

Note that you probably don't want to use `solid_capstyle="butt"` for the `caps`, so the `zorder` way would be the easiest if it doesn't conflict (e.g. transparent box)

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, (ax1, ax2, ax3) = plt.subplots(ncols=3, figsize=(16, 4))

bp = ax1.boxplot([1, 2, 3], patch_artist=True)
plt.setp(bp["boxes"], color="#5454c6")
for item in ["whiskers", "caps"]:
    plt.setp(bp[item], lw=10)

bp = ax2.boxplot([1, 2, 3], patch_artist=True)
plt.setp(bp["boxes"], color="#5454c6")
for item in ["whiskers", "caps"]:
    plt.setp(bp[item], lw=10, solid_capstyle="butt")

bp = ax3.boxplot([1, 2, 3], patch_artist=True)
plt.setp(bp["boxes"], color="#5454c6")
for item in ["whiskers", "caps"]:
    plt.setp(bp[item], lw=10, solid_capstyle="butt", zorder=0)

plt.show()
```

[image: boxplots]